# C# generic method that takes multiple classes

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create a generic method like this one:

```
public static List<T> Filter(this List<T> list, string search) where T : class  
{
    return list.Where(t => t.Name.FormatSearch().Contains(search)).ToList();  
}
```

And to be albe to call this method on different classes and get the same result because both classes have mostly the same attributes.

```
class A {
    public string Name;
}

class B {
    public string Name;
}

var a = new List<A>();
var b = new List<B>();

a.Filter();
b.Filter();
```

I expect the filter method to work the same way for both A and B. What Am I'm missing in the first method?

Comment: What goes wrong with your code?

Comment: Sounds like you want `A` and `B` to have a common interface maybe - it's not clear (to me) what you're asking.

Comment: @AntonioPapa you should create Interface `IName` and declare `Name` Property there. `A` and `B` should implement `IName`. after than write `T` parameter constraint as follows `where T : IName`. After that you will avoid red line under t.Name...` .

Comment: @tchelidze I think you gave me the answer thank you I will check it now

Comment: @AntonioPapa glad if helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do that is to create `Interface` `IName` and declare `Name` Property there.

`A` and `B` should implement `IName`.

Write `T` parameter constraint as follows `where T : IName`

After that you will avoid red line under `t.Name...`

Try following .

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestField
{
   class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var a = new List<A>();
      var b = new List<B>();

      a.Filter("string");
      b.Filter("string");

     }
  }
  public static class Extensions
  {
    public static List<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, string search)
    where T : IName 
    => list.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(search)).ToList();
  }

  public interface IName
  {
    string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class A : IName
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

 public class B : IName
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Comment: @AntonioPapa glad if helped

Answer (score 1):

The answer was given by @tchelidze this is what I wanted to do:

```
public interface IName
{
    string Name { set; get; }
}

class A : IName {
    public string Name
}

class B : IName {
    public string Name
}

public static List<T> Filter<T>(this List<T> list, string search) where T : IName
{
    return list.Where(t => t.Name.FormatSearch().Contains(search)).ToList();  
}
```